# Python: circular imports needed for type checking

Tags: python, import, circular-dependency

First of all: I do know that there are already many questions and answers to the topic of the circular imports.

The answer is more or less: "Design your Module/Class structure properly and you will not need circular imports". That is true. I tried very hard to make a proper design for my current project, I in my opinion I was successful with this.

But my specific problem is the following: I need a type check in a module that is already imported by the module containing the class to check against. But this throws an import error.

Like so:

foo.py:

```
from bar import Bar

class Foo(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.__bar = Bar(self)
```

bar.py:

```
from foo import Foo

class Bar(object):

    def __init__(self, arg_instance_of_foo):
        if not isinstance(arg_instance_of_foo, Foo):
            raise TypeError()
```

**Solution 1:** If I modified it to check the type by a string comparison, it will work. But I dont really like this solution (string comparsion is rather expensive for a simple type check, and could get a problem when it comes to refactoring).

bar_modified.py:

```
from foo import Foo

class Bar(object):

    def __init__(self, arg_instance_of_foo):
        if not arg_instance_of_foo.__class__.__name__ == "Foo":
            raise TypeError()
```

**Solution 2:** I could also pack the two classes into one module. But my project has lots of different classes like the "Bar" example, and I want to seperate them into different module files.

*After my own 2 solutions are no option for me: Has anyone a nicer solution for this problem?*

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39740632/python-type-hinting-without-cyclic-imports for the correct answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The best solution is to not check types.

The other solution is to not create an instance of, and not reference at all, `Foo` or `Bar` until both classes are loaded. If the first module is loaded first, don't create a `Bar` or refer to `Bar` until after the `class Foo` statement is executed. Similarly, if the second module is loaded first, don't create a `Foo` or reference `Foo` until after the `class Bar` statement is executed.

This is basically the source of the `ImportError`, which could be avoided if you did "import foo" and "import bar" instead, and used `foo.Foo` where you now use `Foo`, and `bar.Bar` where you now use `Bar`. In doing this, you no longer refer to either of them until a `Foo` or `Bar` is created, which hopefully won't happen until after both are created (or else you'll get an `AttributeError`).

Answer (score 7):

You can program against `interface` (ABC - [abstract base class](http://docs.python.org/library/abc.html) in python), and not specific type `Bar`. This is classical way to resolve package/module inter-dependencies in many languages. Conceptually it should also result in better object model design.

In your case you would define interface `IBar` in some other module (or even in module that contains Foo class - depends on the usage of that `abc`). You code then looks like this:

foo.py:

```
from bar import Bar, IFoo

class Foo(IFoo):
    def __init__(self):
        self.__bar = Bar(self)

# todo: remove this, just sample code
f = Foo()
b = Bar(f)
print f
print b
x = Bar('do not fail me please') # this fails
```

bar.py:

```
from abc import ABCMeta
class IFoo:
    __metaclass__ = ABCMeta

class Bar(object):
    def __init__(self, arg_instance_of_foo):
        if not isinstance(arg_instance_of_foo, IFoo):
            raise TypeError()
```

Comment: >> :) fair enough. In Java and other strong typed languages such issues appear quite often and have some "standard" solutions. This is "not a problem" in Python where duck typing is just "the way". Nonetheless, I assumed that once the question has been asked, there is a "requirement" to ensure the type.

Answer (score 2):

You could just defer the import in bar.py like this:

```
class Bar(object):

    def __init__(self, arg_instance_of_foo):
        from foo import Foo
        if not isinstance(arg_instance_of_foo, Foo):
            raise TypeError()
```

Comment: All imports should go at the top, unless there's a *really* good reason to not do it. This isn't it.

Comment: @Devin: Your answer is better, but this is a standard way of handling circular imports so the answer is still worthwhile.

Comment: @Devin Jeanpierre: What else could I do?

Comment: @FogleBird: It's no standard (or idiom, etc.) that I've heard of.

Answer (score 1):

Possible duplicate: [Python type hinting without cyclic imports](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39740632/python-type-hinting-without-cyclic-imports?noredirect=1&lq=1)

You should use [Forward Reference](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0484/#forward-references) (PEP 484 - Type Hints):

> When a type hint contains names that have not been defined yet, that definition may be expressed as a string literal, to be resolved later.

So instead of:

```
class Tree:
    def __init__(self, left: Tree, right: Tree):
        self.left = left
        self.right = right
```

do:

```
class Tree:
    def __init__(self, left: 'Tree', right: 'Tree'):
        self.left = left
        self.right = right
```

Comment: type hinting != type checking