# How do I correctly add type-hints to Mixin classes?

Tags: python, oop, type-hinting, mypy, python-typing

Consider the following example. The example is contrived but illustrates the point in a runnable example:

```
class MultiplicatorMixin:

    def multiply(self, m: int) -> int:
        return self.value * m


class AdditionMixin:

    def add(self, b: int) -> int:
        return self.value + b


class MyClass(MultiplicatorMixin, AdditionMixin):

    def __init__(self, value: int) -> None:
        self.value = value


instance = MyClass(10)
print(instance.add(2))
print(instance.multiply(2))
```

When executed this will give the following output:

```
12
20
```

The code works.

But running `mypy` on it, yields the following errors:

```
example.py:4: error: "MultiplicatorMixin" has no attribute "value"
example.py:10: error: "AdditionMixin" has no attribute "value"
```

I understand why mypy gives this result. But the mixin classes are never used by themselves. They are always used as additional superclasses.

For context, this is a pattern which has been used in an existing application and I am in the process of adding type-hints. And in this case, the errors are false-positives. I am thinking about rewriting the part using the mixins as I don't particularly like it and the same could probably be done with reorganising the class hierarchy.

But I still would like to know how something like this could be properly hinted.

Comment: Are the type hints what *cause* the `mypy` error? Or do you still get those errors without the type hints? If that's the case, then type hints have nothing to do with the problem, and I think your question should be *"How do I deal with missing attribute errors in mypy?"*

Comment: @JonathonReinhart I don't underastand what you mean. If I remove the type-hints, then `mypy` will no longer do anything (by assuming everything is of type `Any`). So I don't see the point in doing that. FWIW, I removed the type hints and ran it again, and as expected, the errors are gone (as everything is `Any`).

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't familiar with mypy, and assumed it was just a pylint-style checker. Still, I feel like this doesn't really have anything to do with the type hints themselves, and is just a limitation of the mypy tool.

Comment: Absolutely possible. But in that case it would be good to know of any kind of best-practice in that case. I could sprinkle some `# type: ignore` comments around, but I would like to see if there is an alternative before completely disabling type-checks.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

In addition to Campi's answer about [the mypy's recommendation of typing mixins with `Protocol`](https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/more_types.html#mixin-classes):

An alternative to typing the methods' `self`s is just inheriting the protocol.

```py
from typing import Protocol


class HasValueProtocol(Protocol):
    @property
    def value(self) -> int: ...


class MultiplicationMixin(HasValueProtocol):

    def multiply(self, m: int) -> int:
        return self.value * m


class AdditionMixin(HasValueProtocol):

    def add(self, b: int) -> int:
        return self.value + b


class MyClass(MultiplicationMixin, AdditionMixin):

    def __init__(self, value: int) -> None:
        self.value = value
```

---

Additionally, if you are [`TYPE_CHECKING`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.TYPE_CHECKING) a `Protocol`, and given that you cannot forward reference a parent class (i.e. passing the parent class as a string literal), a workaround would be:

```py
from typing import Protocol, TYPE_CHECKING


if TYPE_CHECKING:
    class HasValueProtocol(Protocol):
        @property
        def value(self) -> int: ...
else:
    class HasValueProtocol: ...


class MultiplicationMixin(HasValueProtocol):
    def multiply(self, m: int) -> int:
        return self.value * m

...
```

Comment: This feels far nicer than the answer I currently accepted and is much more in line with the current state. Thanks for the update. Note: I think you meant "Campi" instead of "Dec" ;)

Comment: @exhuma LOL. I confused month and username ;)

Comment: This is a much nicer answer than typing the individual "self" arguments, because typing `self` as the Protocol prevents you from accessing attributes on the Mixin class itself. (It is just the Protocol)

Comment: But this makes `MultiplicationMixin` a `Protocol`, which is kinda wrong if a `Procotol` isn't supposed to contain actual code?

Comment: @TuukkaMustonen Nope. A class needs to explicitly inherit from `Protocol` to become a protocol (`class MultiplicationMixin(HasValueProtocol, Protocol): ...`). Otherwise, it just inherits the protocol's default implementation. And, in any case, a protocol _can_ contain actual code.

Comment: Cool. Thanks for clarifying that!

Comment: I have found this issue run into the problem of `AttributeError: can't set attribute` if the `value` property in this case is assigned within the concrete implementation. Is there any solution to this?

Comment: @MattLyon You need to implement a [`@value.setter` method](https://python-reference.readthedocs.io/en/latest/docs/property/setter.html).

Comment: @NunoAndré I thought of this, but if you do this then you get a recursion error. You can see an example of this here https://gist.github.com/m-lyon/507b6bcdeadd0e6ba0bab0ec068a86ff

Comment: @MattLyon Answered in the gist.

Comment: Campi's answer will fail if your mixin defines multiple methods which need to access each other (because you're annotating `self` with the fields, not the mixin itself anymore). This answer will work, and you can also inherit from any other required types, whereas protocols can only inherit from protocols.

Comment: Can someone explain "Additionally, if you are TYPE_CHECKING ..." part?

Comment: @NpnSaddy `TYPE_CHECKING` is `True` during a statical analysis and `False` during the code execution. So, if you have some computationally expensive typing you can wrap it in this way and avoid this cost.

Comment: @NunoAndré I know the use of `TYPE_CHECKING`. I was asking about `class` defined inside both `if..else`. I copy pasted above code which uses inheritance from protocol. I'm seeing mypy errors on inherited `MultiplicationMixin` class as 
```Class derives from one or more protocol classes but does not implement all required members
  Member "value" is declared in protocol class "HasValueProtocol"```

Comment: @NpnSaddy That's not a mypy error, but a PyRight's one (mypy doesn't complain about this). Also, it has nothing to do with `TYPE_CHECKING` (you get the same error without it), but with a [design decision of PyRight that goes against PEP 544 (i.e. a Protocol is not an ABC)](https://github.com/microsoft/pyright/issues/3730) (I strongly agree with OP's POV). Given that PyRight doesn't have a specific opt-out on this (it marks it as a `reportGeneralTypeIssues`), a quick fix would be substitute `...` with `raise NotImplementedError`. But I prefer to just ignore it.

Comment: This approach doesn't seem to work if the child class (e.g.: `MyClass` in the example) has other supertypes. I'm seeing: `TypeError: metaclass conflict: the metaclass of a derived class must be a (non-strict) subclass of the metaclasses of all its bases
`

Comment: Moving the protocol into `if TYPE_CHECKING` helps, but I can't figure out how to all methods on the superclass from inside the mixing. E.g.: `Call to abstract method "get_urls" of "InterfaceImportExportAdmin" with trivial body via super() is unsafe`

Comment: @WhyNotHugo Maybe has something to do with https://github.com/python/mypy/issues/14757 ?

Comment: This doesn't actually seem to type check with `pyright`? I complains on the declaration of `AdditionMixin` that `Class derives from one or more protocol classes but does not implement all required members
  Member "value" is declared in protocol class "HasValueProtocol"` which makes sense: the class does not implement the protocol, after all.

Comment: @BeeOnRope Yes, this is an arbitrary decision by the owner of PyRight (discussed a few comments above). But mypy is developed by the Python Software Foundation and implements the standard, while PyRight is developed by Microsoft. So I have no doubt which way to go ;)

Comment: Be careful about directly inheriting the protocol. If what we want to annotate is not an attribute (`value` in the  above example)  but a method, and it  needs to call the super().method recursively (typical in the scenario of multiple inheritance), and this method in protocol is abstract (function body is `...`), the super call chain will be interrupted.

Comment: @sigmaticz That behavior [is documented](https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/protocols.html#defining-subprotocols-and-subclassing-protocols). And anyway, why would you want to define a method as abstract if not to inherit from its class?

Answer (score 69):

For reference, mypy recommends to implement mixins through a [`Protocol`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.Protocol) (documentation [here](https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/more_types.html#mixin-classes)).

It works with mypy >= 750.

```
from typing import Protocol


class HasValueProtocol(Protocol):
    @property
    def value(self) -> int: ...


class MultiplicationMixin:

    def multiply(self: HasValueProtocol, m: int) -> int:
        return self.value * m


class AdditionMixin:

    def add(self: HasValueProtocol, b: int) -> int:
        return self.value + b


class MyClass(MultiplicationMixin, AdditionMixin):

    def __init__(self, value: int) -> None:
        self.value = value
```

The `Protocol` base class is provided in the `typing_extensions` package for Python 2.7 and 3.4-3.7.

Comment: Yes. I saw the announcement yesterday. This is really a nice addition. Can't wait until our servers support this!

Comment: A big downside of using `self: HasValueProtocol` in methods for `AdditionMixin` is that `self` is no longer of type `AdditionMixin`. This makes it an error to try and call other methods defined in `AdditionMixin` from inside the body of these methods.

Comment: @WhyNotHugo this concern (actually, huge limitation) seems to be avoided in [the other answer to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70907644/1509695) which is suggesting to inherit the protocol rather than coerce the self type. This still feels a little shaky, I doubt why mypy suggest this while protocols were primarily designed for duck-typing and not inheritance. Feels patchy to me. I'll be using an abstract class instead, as my IDE has very poor and misleading static analysis support for protocols.

Answer (score 12):

One approach I saw in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39740632/458274) is type hinting the `self` attribute. Together with `Union` from the typing package, you are able to use the attributes from a class which is used together with your mixin, while still having correct type hinting for own attributes:

```
from typing import Union

class AdditionMixin:

    def add(self: Union[MyBaseClass, 'AdditionMixin'], b: int) -> int:
        return self.value + b


class MyBaseClass:

    def __init__(self, value: int):
        self.value = value
```

Downside is that you have to add the hint to every method, which is kind of cumbersome.

Comment: Wouldn't this defeat the purpose of the mixin though? Because now you can only use it with subclasses of `MyBaseClass`. Meaning that you could also just move the `add` method into `MyBaseClass`

Comment: In my case, I'm building mixins for the django-rest-framework, which also comes with a couple of mixins: https://github.com/encode/django-rest-framework/blob/master/rest_framework/mixins.py
The mixins are always used together with the [GenericAPIView](https://github.com/encode/django-rest-framework/blob/master/rest_framework/generics.py#L26), giving basic functionality, while each mixin provides a different additional feature

Comment: Simplified: `MyBaseClass` could provide various calculations, but the user should choose which ones are supported. `MyBaseClass` provides a `value` attribute, and the users choose which of the mixins `AdditionMixin`, `SubtractionMixin`, `DivisionMixin` and `MultiplicationMixin` they need in their application

Comment: @exhuma no: it's not a problem if a mixin declares some expectations about the class it wants to mix into :) Protocols serve this purpose better, though

Answer (score 8):

Try with:

````py
from typing import Type, TYPE_CHECKING, TypeVar

T = TypeVar('T')


def with_typehint(baseclass: Type[T]) -> Type[T]:
    """
    Useful function to make mixins with baseclass typehint

    ```
    class ReadonlyMixin(with_typehint(BaseAdmin)):
        ...
    ```
    """
    if TYPE_CHECKING:
        return baseclass
    return object
````

Example tested in Pyright:

```py
class ReadOnlyInlineMixin(with_typehint(BaseModelAdmin)):
    def get_readonly_fields(self,
                            request: WSGIRequest,
                            obj: Optional[Model] = None) -> List[str]:

        if self.readonly_fields is None:
            readonly_fields = []
        else:
            readonly_fields = self.readonly_fields # self get is typed by baseclass

        return self._get_readonly_fields(request, obj) + list(readonly_fields)

    def has_change_permission(self,
                              request: WSGIRequest,
                              obj: Optional[Model] = None) -> bool:
        return (
            request.method in ['GET', 'HEAD']
            and super().has_change_permission(request, obj) # super is typed by baseclass
        )

>>> ReadOnlyAdminMixin.__mro__
(<class 'custom.django.admin.mixins.ReadOnlyAdminMixin'>, <class 'object'>)
```

Comment: This seems overly convoluted *just* to get type-hints.

Comment: Yes but is also kind of smart. As long as there is no official Implementation this seems my preferred way to got.
For reference [here the link](https://github.com/python/typing/issues/246#issuecomment-656350882) the same proposal in a mypy issue.

Comment: @exhuma It's necessary for mixin classes for frameworks such as Qt, that use custom metaclasses defined in C, where it's invalid to double inherit from multiple Qt base classes

Answer (score 4):

I've tested it on my machine, hope it will also work for you:

```
class MultiplicatorMixin:
    value = None # type: int

    def multiply(self, m: int) -> int:
        return self.value * m


class AdditionMixin:
    value = None # type: int

    def add(self, b: int) -> int:
        return self.value + b


class MyClass(MultiplicatorMixin, AdditionMixin):

    def __init__(self, value: int) -> None:
        self.value = value


instance = MyClass(10)
print(instance.add(2))
print(instance.multiply(2))
```

Comment: And when `MyClass` has a whole lot of attributes, I would end up copying all of them, having a maintenance hell especially if `MyClass` is from an external dependency. I don't think this is a viable solution.

Comment: I actually think this is the proper solution. You only need to add class-level attributes for the value with which the mixin is concerned about. Which makes perfect sense.

Comment: @soerface Fine, It depends. For my use cases, `Mixin` can be used by multiple Superclasses in order to gain some additional functionalities. If you use multiple `Mixin` to support only one Superclass, this is not for you.

Comment: Isn't this solution problematic when in models of ORMs? Could adding a class variable lead to a new attribute in the ORM?

Answer (score 3):

My solution: add a `value: int` without any init to Mixin class:

```
class MultiplicatorMixin:
    value: int

    def multiply(self, m: int) -> int:
        return self.value * m


class AdditionMixin:
    value: int

    def add(self, b: int) -> int:
        return self.value + b


class MyClass(MultiplicatorMixin, AdditionMixin):

    def __init__(self, value: int) -> None:
        self.value = value


instance = MyClass(10)
print(instance.add(2))
print(instance.multiply(2))
```

Comment: I'm wondering what could be the issues with applying this solution since it doesn't have many upvotes. I can see that it works fine with minimum code to add?

Comment: Doesn't that make `value` a static class variable?

Answer (score 2):

In addition to good answers mentioned above. My use case - mixins to be used in tests.

As proposed by Guido van Rossum himself [here](https://github.com/python/typing/issues/241#issuecomment-332234939):

```py
from typing import *
T = TypeVar('T')

class Base:
    fit: Callable

class Foo(Base):
    def fit(self, arg1: int) -> Optional[str]:
        pass

class Bar(Foo):
    def fit(self, arg1: float) -> str:
        pass
```

Thus, when it comes to a mixin, it could look as follows:

```py
class UsefulMixin:

    assertLess: Callable
    assertIn: Callable
    assertIsNotNone: Callable

    def something_useful(self, key, value):
        self.assertIsNotNone(key)
        self.assertLess(key, 10)
        self.assertIn(value, ['Alice', 'in', 'Wonderland']


class AnotherUsefulMixin:

    assertTrue: Callable
    assertFalse: Callable
    assertIsNone: Callable

    def something_else_useful(self, val, foo, bar):
        self.assertTrue(val)
        self.assertFalse(foo)
        self.assertIsNone(bar)
```

And our final class would look as follows:

```py
class TestSomething(unittest.TestCase, UsefulMixin, AnotherUsefulMixin):

    def test_something(self):
        self.something_useful(10, 'Alice')
        self.something_else_useful(True, False, None)
```

Comment: @exhuma: It's a complementary answer, which does not only cover variables, but also a way to deal with callables. It also contains useful information on what the creator of Python himself thinks of it. If Sraw would update his answer with this information (which was useful to me, as I didn't find what I was looking for) or someone else would take that initiative (I'm not sure if it's allowed or not), I'm willing to remove mine.

Comment: Please don't take this the wrong way, I am mainly worried that I am missing something and that maybe I can learn something from your answer: I still don't see the difference. The only difference I can make out is that it is using annotations instead of the `# type: ...` comment. Using `assertLess = None  # type: Callable` should be the same. Or am I missing something?

Comment: @exhauma: AFAIK ``assertLess = None  # type: Callable`` is Python 2 way of doing this, since real typing had been introduced in Python 3.6 only. Thus, nowadays using typing explicitly is better. Besides, the most valuable thing for me that I have found in the link I mentioned in my answer, is the approach van Guido van Rossum himself. For me, his answer there, in that GitHub issue - was the best. :)

Comment: The type-comment is also valid for Python <3.6. It is correct that this syntax was introduced in 3.6, but type-hints (or rather "annotations") have been around since 3.3 IIRC. I routinely type-check Python 3.5 code so I still rely on the type-comment. I agree that the new 3.6 syntax is cleaner though as technically it would be necessary to write `foo = None  # type: Optional[Callable]` in the old syntax to accommodate for the default value.

Comment: This answer suggests using the same principle as the earlier answer by @Sraw, i.e. adding type hints to the mixin attributes directly. It introduces a maintenance cost of keeping the type hints of every mixin up-to-date with its potential base classes.

Answer (score 1):

One method that you do not have to write type hint at every method:

```
import typing


class FooMixin:
    base = typing.Union["Hello", "World"]

    def alpha(self: base):
        self.hello()

    def beta(self: base):
        self.world()


class Base(object):
    pass


class Hello(Base, FooMixin):
    def hello(self):
        print("hello from", self)


class World(Base, FooMixin):
    def world(self):
        print("world from", self)


Hello().alpha()
World().beta()
```

Answer (score 0):

It's possible to do something like this when using Protocol **and** BaseClass in the mixin:

```py
from typing import TYPE_CHECKING, Protocol, cast


class BaseClass:
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        self.name = "base name"


class SizeProtocol(Protocol):
    size: int


class DoubleSizeMixin:
    """
    Add this mixin to classes implementing `SizeProtocol` and inheriting from `BaseClass`
    """

    def get_double_size_with_name(self) -> tuple:
        _self: "DoubleSizeMixinT" = self  # type: ignore
        return (_self.name, _self.size * 2)

    # Another option:
    def get_double_size_with_name_v2(self) -> tuple:
        self = cast("DoubleSizeMixinT", self)  # pylint: disable=self-cls-assignment
        return (self.name, self.size * 2)


if TYPE_CHECKING:
    class DoubleSizeMixinT(SizeProtocol, DoubleSizeMixin, BaseClass):
        pass


class A(BaseClass, SizeProtocol, DoubleSizeMixin):
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        super().__init__()
        self.size = 2


print(A().get_double_size_with_name())
```