# Mixin Method super() call generates a Unresolved Attribute Reference in PyCharm

Tags: python, pycharm, type-hinting, python-typing

In PyCharm I have some codes that looks like this:

```py
class Mixin:
    def get_form_kwargs(self):
        kwargs = super().get_form_kwargs()
        kwargs.update({'foo': 'bar'})
        return kwargs
```

The linter is raising an issue that `Unresolved attribute reference 'get_form_kwargs' for class 'object'` on the `super()` call.   This issue is 100% true but unhelpful on a mixin.   We have a great many mixins that have this `super()` pattern.

I'm aware of a solution for attributes but not methods where you are able to declare types for these undefined class attributes.  For example:

```py
class Mixin:
    foo:str
```

I am curious if there is anything similar for methods that help the linter to recognize the mixins.

Thanks!

Comment: I think the key is perhaps to hint at the superclass, or at least, hint that the superclass isn't `object`. I've had some success with using `typing.Protocol` or `typing.Generic` as part of a mixin class, e.g., `Mixin(Protocol): ...`; however, I don't know enough about the implications to propose their use as a definite answer.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I correctly add type-hints to Mixin classes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51930339/how-do-i-correctly-add-type-hints-to-mixin-classes)

Answer (score -3):

Try this code:

```
class Mixin:
    def get_form_kwargs(self):
        get_form_kwargs_method = getattr(super(), "get_form_kwargs")
        if get_form_kwargs_method and callable(get_form_kwargs_method):
            kwargs = get_form_kwargs_method()
        else:
            kwargs = {}
        kwargs.update({'foo': 'bar'})
        return kwargs
```

**Update:**
I'd appreciate a comment from those who added `-` on this answer. This definitely fixes a pylint issute. This is not short and elegant, but you have 2 choices: disable this check in pylint or write a valid code.

[image]