# How to correctly add type annotations to python Mixin?

Tags: python, mixins, type-hinting

## The Code Setup

I have the following class that I want to insert a new feature using Mixins:

```
class InputCollection(StringReprMixin, AbstractVariableCollection):
    def __init__(self, data: Optional[ValidInputCollection]):
        super().__init__()
        # rest of the code
```

This is the Mixin implementation I did following the [mypy documentation](https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/more_types.html#mixin-classes) using Protocols:

```
class StringReprMixin:
    def __str__(self: HasEmptyProtocol) -> str:
        if self.empty:
            return "Empty collection."
        else:
            return _collection_to_string(self)
```

The `HasEmptyProtocol` is to enable the mypy checker that the mixin has the `empty`property. The `_collection_to_string` function has the following signature:

```
CollectionType = Union[InputCollection, OutputCollection, ExpressionCollection]

def _collection_to_string(collection: CollectionType):
    # rest of function code
```

## The problem

I don't know how to make the mypy correctly check on the call of `_collection_to_string` in the `StringReprMixin` function, since the mypy checker thinks that the self is a instance of `HasEmptyProtocol` instead of any of the classes in `CollectionType`.

This is the error thrown by the static checker:

`Argument 1 to "_collection_to_string" has incompatible type "HasEmptyProtocol"; expected "Union[InputCollection, OutputCollection, ExpressionCollection]"`

## What I have tried

I've seen some questions/issues, in particular, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51930339/how-do-i-correctly-add-type-hints-to-mixin-classes) one seems to work. However, to me, the use of class attributes in a Mixin defeats the purpose of a Protocol subclass as suggested by the mypy docs.

## What is working for me

I did a [cast](https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/casts.html), together with a [runtime check](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.TYPE_CHECKING), of the `InputCollection` instance before calling `_collection_to_string`:

```
class StringReprMixin:
    def __str__(self: HasEmptyProtocol) -> str:
        if self.empty:
            return "Empty collection."
        else:
            if TYPE_CHECKING:
                self = cast(CollectionType, self)

            return __collection_to_string(self)
```

However, I have no idea if this is proper way handle referencing of instances inside of a Mixin that is type-annotated.

## So the final question is:

**Is this the correct way to annotate this kind Mixin?**