# In Python, how to type hint a class method that uses both properties from a Protocol as well as from the class itself?

Tags: python, mypy, torch, python-typing, pytorch-lightning

I am implementing a class that should support some generic behaviour for setting up train/validation/test DataLoaders with PytorchLightning's `LightningDataModule`. I want to provide some functionality in this generic class, but leave initialising some properties to those that would inherit from it. My try on this problem should illustrate what I have in mind:

```py
from typing import Protocol
import pytorch_lightning as pl
from torch.utils.data import Dataset, DataLoader


class HasTrainValTestDatasets(Protocol):
    @property
    def train_ds(self) -> Dataset: ...

    @property
    def val_ds(self) -> Dataset: ...

    @property
    def test_ds(self) -> Dataset: ...


class GenericTrainValTestDataModule(pl.LightningDataModule):
    def __init__(
        self,
        batch_size_train: int,
        batch_size_eval: int,
        num_workers: int = 0,
    ):
        self._batch_size_train = batch_size_train
        self._batch_size_eval = batch_size_eval
        self._num_workers = num_workers

    def train_dataloader(self: HasTrainValTestDatasets) -> DataLoader:
        return DataLoader(self.train_ds, batch_size=self._batch_size_train, num_workers=self._num_workers)

    def val_dataloader(self: HasTrainValTestDatasets) -> DataLoader:
        return DataLoader(self.val_ds, batch_size=self._batch_size_eval, num_workers=self._num_workers)

    def test_dataloader(self: HasTrainValTestDatasets) -> DataLoader:
        return DataLoader(self.test_ds, batch_size=self._batch_size_eval, num_workers=self._num_workers)
```

I got inspired by this Stack Overflow answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59128961/8543212.

I want to generalise that the `DataLoader`s are created using `batch_size_(train/eval)`and `num_workers` from `train/val/test_ds`, the latter is to be implemented by the class that would inherit from this generic class.

Unfortunately, I can't type hint it correctly. My goal is to use `Protocol` to enforce that users of this generic class provide `train/val/test_ds`. However, I fail to satisfy mypy with the example above because:

```
d.py:30: error: "HasTrainValTestDatasets" has no attribute "_batch_size_train"  [attr-defined]
d.py:30: error: "HasTrainValTestDatasets" has no attribute "_num_workers"  [attr-defined]
d.py:35: error: "HasTrainValTestDatasets" has no attribute "_batch_size_eval"  [attr-defined]
d.py:35: error: "HasTrainValTestDatasets" has no attribute "_num_workers"  [attr-defined]
d.py:40: error: "HasTrainValTestDatasets" has no attribute "_batch_size_eval"  [attr-defined]
d.py:40: error: "HasTrainValTestDatasets" has no attribute "_num_workers"  [attr-defined]
```

Is there a way to tell mypy that `self` is both the `HasTrainValTestDatasets` Protocol and `GenericTrainValTestDataModule`?

For those wondering why insist on such design, I cannot think of better generalisation of https://lightning.ai/docs/pytorch/stable/data/datamodule.html for my purposes (however I may be wrong).

Steps to reproduce (assuming my demo is stored in `d.py`):

```
virtualenv venv
pip install torch pytorch-lightning
mypy --install-types d.py
```

Comment: Stronger than only type-hinting, you should probably just remove the `Protocol`, and add `HasTrainValTestDatasets` as a mix-in abstract parent.

Answer (score 0):

I think I (roughly) found the solution I was looking for:

```
from typing import Protocol
import pytorch_lightning as pl
from torch.utils.data import Dataset, DataLoader
from torchvision.datasets import FakeData
from torchvision.transforms import ToTensor


class HasTrainValTestDatasets(Protocol):
    train_ds: Dataset
    val_ds: Dataset
    test_ds: Dataset


class GenericTrainValTestDataModule(pl.LightningDataModule, HasTrainValTestDatasets):
    def __init__(self, batch_size_train: int, batch_size_eval: int, num_workers: int = 0):
        self._batch_size_train = batch_size_train
        self._batch_size_eval = batch_size_eval
        self._num_workers = num_workers

    def train_dataloader(self) -> DataLoader:
        return DataLoader(self.train_ds, batch_size=self._batch_size_train, num_workers=self._num_workers)

    def val_dataloader(self) -> DataLoader:
        return DataLoader(self.val_ds, batch_size=self._batch_size_eval, num_workers=self._num_workers)

    def test_dataloader(self) -> DataLoader:
        return DataLoader(self.test_ds, batch_size=self._batch_size_eval, num_workers=self._num_workers)


class ConcreteDataModuleOk(GenericTrainValTestDataModule):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__(8, 8, 0)
        self.train_ds = FakeData(transform=ToTensor())
        self.val_ds = FakeData(transform=ToTensor())
        self.test_ds = FakeData(transform=ToTensor())


class ConcreteDataModuleBad(GenericTrainValTestDataModule):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__(8, 8, 0)

cdm_ok = ConcreteDataModuleOk()

print(cdm_ok.train_ds[0][0].shape)
print(next(iter(cdm_ok.train_dataloader()))[0].shape)

cdm_bad = ConcreteDataModuleBad()  # <-- mypy will complain here
```

After extra `pip install -r torchvision` when I run: `mypy --ignore-missing d1.py` I get:

```
d.py:49: error: Cannot instantiate abstract class "ConcreteDataModuleBad" with abstract attributes "test_ds", "train_ds" and "val_ds"  [abstract]
Found 1 error in 1 file (checked 1 source file)
```

Which is exactly what I wanted to achieve. If I remove `Protocol`, mypy fails to recognise the problem, so I guess Protocol does its job. One caveat is that, for some reason, it fails to recognise when `train/val/test_ds` has wrong type (e.g. string instead of `Dataset`), but I can work with that.

Also, as @Reinderien said, this can probably be done with abstract classes too (maybe with the same result)? I'll stick to my solution since it looks comfortably concise to me.