# How do I correctly add type-hints to complex Mixin classes?

Tags: python, annotations, mypy, mixins

What is the correct way to add type annotations to a mixin class like the following to make the code pass a mypy-check:

example1.py:

```
class HostClass:
    def host_method(self) -> None:
        pass

    def overridden_host_method(self) -> None:
        pass

class MixinClass:
    def mixin_method(self) -> None:
        self._other_mixin_method()
        self.host_method()

    def _other_mixin_method(self) -> None:
        pass

    def overridden_host_method(self) -> None:
        super().overridden_host_method()


class MyClass(MixinClass, HostClass):
    pass


obj = MyClass()
obj.mixin_method()
obj.overridden_host_method()
```

```
% mypy example1.py
example1.py:11: error: "MixinClass" has no attribute "host_method"  [attr-defined]
example1.py:17: error: "overridden_host_method" undefined in superclass  [misc]
Found 2 errors in 1 file (checked 1 source file)
```

The recommended solution in the mypy documentation (https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/more_types.html#mixin-classes) and in the answers to [How do I correctly add type-hints to Mixin classes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51930339/how-do-i-correctly-add-type-hints-to-mixin-classes) do not work.

example2.py (HostProtocol as type annotation for "self"):

```
from typing import Protocol


class HostProtocol(Protocol):
    def host_method(self) -> None:
        ...

    def overridden_host_method(self) -> None:
        ...


class HostClass:
    def host_method(self) -> None:
        pass

    def overridden_host_method(self) -> None:
        pass


class MixinClass:
    def mixin_method(self: HostProtocol) -> None:
        self._other_mixin_method()
        self.host_method()

    def _other_mixin_method(self) -> None:
        pass

    def overridden_host_method(self) -> None:
        super().overridden_host_method()


class MyClass(MixinClass, HostClass):
    pass


obj = MyClass()
obj.mixin_method()
obj.overridden_host_method()
```

```
% mypy example2.py
example2.py:22: error: "HostProtocol" has no attribute "_other_mixin_method"  [attr-defined]
example2.py:29: error: "overridden_host_method" undefined in superclass  [misc]
Found 2 errors in 1 file (checked 1 source file)
```

example3.py (HostProtocol as base class of MixinClass):

```
from typing import Protocol

class HostProtocol(Protocol):
    def host_method(self) -> None:
        ...
 
    def overridden_host_method(self) -> None:
        ...


class HostClass:
    def host_method(self) -> None:
        pass

    def overridden_host_method(self) -> None:
        pass

class MixinClass(HostProtocol):
    def mixin_method(self) -> None:
        self._other_mixin_method()
        self.host_method()

    def _other_mixin_method(self) -> None:
        pass

    def overridden_host_method(self) -> None:
        super().overridden_host_method()


class MyClass(MixinClass, HostClass):
    pass


obj = MyClass()
obj.mixin_method()
obj.overridden_host_method()
```

```
% mypy example3.py
example3.py:34: error: Cannot instantiate abstract class "MyClass" with abstract attribute "host_method"  [abstract]
example3.py:34: note: "host_method" is implicitly abstract because it has an empty function body. If it is not meant to be abstract, explicitly `return` or `return None`.
Found 1 error in 1 file (checked 1 source file)
```

example4.py (switching the order of the base classes of MyClass):

```
from typing import Protocol

class HostProtocol(Protocol):
    def host_method(self) -> None:
        ...
 
    def overridden_host_method(self) -> None:
        ...


class HostClass:
    def host_method(self) -> None:
        pass

    def overridden_host_method(self) -> None:
        pass

class MixinClass(HostProtocol):
    def mixin_method(self) -> None:
        self._other_mixin_method()
        self.host_method()

    def _other_mixin_method(self) -> None:
        pass

    def overridden_host_method(self) -> None:
        print("Mixin overrides")
        super().overridden_host_method()


class MyClass(HostClass, MixinClass):
    pass


obj = MyClass()
obj.mixin_method()
obj.overridden_host_method()
```

```
mypy example4.py
Success: no issues found in 1 source file
```

But overridden_host_method() is not overridden anymore:

```
% python example4.py
%
```

i. e. "Mixin overrides" is not printed.

The MixinClass shall:

- call a method from the HostClass
- call also a method from itself
- override a method of the HostClass

Answer (score 1):

The recommendation to use `typing.Protocol`s is given on the basis of minimising the difference between runtime and static typing. However, I would avoid `typing.Protocol` for most cases, including mixin classes. they are not easy to use, as you've found in your `example2.py` (annotating `self` is awkward without [intersection types](https://github.com/python/typing/issues/213)) and `example3.py` (base class order is awkward to get right, if it's possible at all; this also introduces a hidden metaclass).

If you extensively rely on static typing and don't mind differences between runtime and static typing, then there is a better solution for mixin classes.

```py
from __future__ import annotations

import typing_extensions as t

if t.TYPE_CHECKING:
    MixinBase: t.TypeAlias = "HostClass"
else:
    MixinBase = object

class HostClass:
    def host_method(self) -> None: pass
    def overridden_host_method(self) -> None: pass

class MixinClass(MixinBase):
    def mixin_method(self) -> None:
        self._other_mixin_method()
        self.host_method()                       # No Errors

    def _other_mixin_method(self) -> None: pass

    def overridden_host_method(self) -> None:
        super().overridden_host_method()         # No Errors

class MyClass(MixinClass, HostClass): pass
```

```
>>> obj = MyClass()
>>> obj.mixin_method()
>>> obj.overridden_host_method()
```