# What are the effects of not passing a "master" to a widget?

Tags: python, tkinter

As I work on a GUI I have encountered the problem of [cyclic imports due to type hinting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39740632/python-type-hinting-without-cyclic-imports) and the answer supplied works, but it starts to pollute source code since every widget class imports the class it needs to instantiate and every instantiated widget needs to import the caller so that it may type hint:

```
# navbar.py

import tkinter as tk
from filemenu import FileMenu

class NavBar(tk.Menu):

    def __init__(self, parent: tk.Tk, **kwargs) -> None:
        super().__init__(parent, **kwargs)
        self.add_cascade(label='File', menu=FileMenu(self, tearoff=False))


# filemenu.py

import tkinter as tk
from typing import TYPE_CHECKING:
    from navbar import NavBar
# from navbar import NavBar  # using this causes cyclic import failure

class FileMenu(tk.Menu):

    def __init__(self, parent: 'NavBar', **kwargs) -> None:
        super().__init__(parent, **kwargs)
        self.add_command(label='Settings', command=self.open_settings)

    def open_settings(self) -> None:

        print(self.master.__class__)
```

The `NavBar` class instantiates a `FileMenu` class, and therefore the module must import `FileMenu`. The problem comes inside `filemenu.py` where the `__init__` parameter `parent` is typed as the parent widget, in this case a `NavBar` instance. In order to do this, `navbar.py` must be imported and cyclic imports begin.

However, I gave this a try with a `Menu` that had a dropdown:

```
# navbar.py

import tkinter as tk
from filemenu import FileMenu

class NavBar(tk.Menu):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs) -> None:
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.add_cascade(label='File', menu=FileMenu(tearoff=False))


# filemenu.py

import tkinter as tk

class FileMenu(tk.Menu):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs) -> None:
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.add_command(label='Settings', command=self.open_settings)

    def open_settings(self) -> None:

        print(self.master.__class__)

# main.py

import tkinter as tk

from navbar import NavBar

if __name__ == '__main__':
    root = tk.Tk()
    root.configure(menu=NavBar())
    root.mainloop()
```

Opens a window with a dropdown menu that prints the `tk.Tk()` as the `self.master.__class__`.

Are there effects from not passing a `master` parameter around? The effbot documentation shows it as `master=None` for most (if not all) widgets, therefore optional.

Comment: The default `master` is whatever instance of `Tk()` your program created first.  If you rely on this default, you'd have a hard time doing any sort of advanced widget layout - no grids inside a grid cell, for example.  But I have no idea what you mean by "every instantiated widget needs to import the caller so that it may type hint" - objects should *never* need to know who is going to use them.  I think you may be too specific in your type hint - `tk.BaseWidget` should suffice for the `master` parameter.

Comment: @jasonharper Please see my edit post. The top block shows how I would normally type annotate but am forced to use the `TYPE_CHECKING` constant for third-party static analysis tools. Using the absolute import of a `NavBar` inside the `filemenu.py` results in a cyclic import. Another alternative is to type the `parent` of a `FileMenu` instance as `tk.Menu`, however should it not be explicit that it be typed as the concrete type it is passed, i.e. a `NavBar` type?

Comment: Why should `FileMenu` care exactly what sort of menu bar it's part of?  That's not its job... and you're completely throwing away the whole concept of software module reusability by tying it to a specific class.

Comment: @jasonharper That's reasonable. Linters don't like it though. For example if `NavBar` has an attribute `foo`, the linter cannot resolve `parent.foo` since its hinted as a `tk.Menu`. Beyond that, not every module should be scoped for reusability should it? I only ever intend for there to be a single navigation bar in the application. Why make it reusable?

Comment: Well, if you're accessing a non-standard attribute of the parent widget, then you *are* tied to that specific class, and explicitly naming it becomes appropriate.  The solution in that case is to *stop splitting your classes into single files*, this isn't Java after all.

Comment: @jasonharper Thats probably my issue, designing this Python application with my Java import/DI sequence in mind.

Answer (score 0):

> Are there effects from not passing a master parameter around?

Widgets exist in a tree-like hierarchy. Every widget except the root widget must have a parent (or sometimes called a *master*). If you do not supply a parent, the root window will be used as the parent. Except for very simple programs, that is usually not the correct thing to do.