# Python type hints with imported class methods

Tags: python, python-3.7, type-hinting, python-typing

In order to split a large class into multiple files, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47562412/10155767), recommends using the `import` command at the `class` level to load methods whose definitions can be moved to other modules. As a minimal example,

`class_def.py`:

```py
class C:
    from _methods import m
```

`_methods.py`:

```py
def m(self):
    return "hello"
```

Normally, most IDEs which feature code completion will recognize functions which are defined in some class as bound methods, and `self` will automatically be recognized as having the type of the class where the method was defined. Unfortunately, in the above situation, I have not defined `m` inside of a class. It is impossible to tell from looking at just `_methods.py` that `self` should have type `C`.

In the definition of `m`, if I insert a line which starts with `self.`, my IDE cannot suggest `m` or any other methods which I might have implemented in `C`.

The obvious solution would be to add a type hint:

```
from class_def import C

def m(self: C):
    return "hello"
```

But now we have a circular import: the definition of `C` imports `_methods`, but `_methods` imports `C`. How can I create a type hint without introducing a circular import?

I am currently using Python 3.7, but I would also be interested in solutions requiring later versions.

Comment: If a class becomes that big, that you have to split it, there's a good chance that something in your design is suboptimal. I would suggest spending some time in refactoring.

Comment: I find it hard to imagine a more ideal way than this to refactor a large class which represents an object that should have a large amount of functionality. But that could be my ignorance (I'm not a programmer).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python type hinting without cyclic imports](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39740632/python-type-hinting-without-cyclic-imports)

Comment: @Georgy, almost. I think the answer below answers that question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Fix the circular import by using the `typing.TYPE_CHECKING` flag to import `C` only during type checking.
2. This leaves the value of `C` undefined at runtime. Either enclose it in quotes (`"C"`) or import `__future__.annotations`:

`_methods.py` variant 1:

```py
from typing import TYPE_CHECKING

if TYPE_CHECKING:
    from class_def import C

def m(self: "C"):
    return "hello"
```

`_methods.py` variant 2:

```py
from __future__ import annotations
from typing import TYPE_CHECKING

if TYPE_CHECKING:
    from class_def import C

def m(self: C):
    return "hello"
```