# Python Forward References for Package Objects

Tags: python, python-3.x, type-hinting, python-typing

I suspect the answer is yes, but I wanted to ask just to be clear. If I have a function that expects to use, for example, a `numpy` object, but I am not using `numpy` directly in my module, can I use a forward reference to type hint my argument rather than import `numpy` directly?

In other words (assuming Python 3.7+), can I do this

```py
# forward-reference.py

def my_func(arr: "np.ndarray") -> int:
    # does some operations with arr
```

instead of this

```py
# direct-import.py

import numpy as np

def my_func(arr: np.ndarray) -> int:
    # do some operations on arr...
```

I can't imagine the core developers would require programmers to import a module simply for type hinting. My `pylint` or `flake8` linters would correctly pick those up as unused modules and I think all those extra imports would be quite redundant.

### Edit

To test, I created two files: `demo1.py` and `demo2.py` (both live in the same directory):

#### demo1.py

```py
# demo1.py

import numpy as np

from demo2 import my_func

if __name__ == "__main__":
    a = np.array([1, 2, 3])
    print(my_func(a))
```

#### demo2.py

```py
# demo2.py

def my_func(arr: "np.ndarray") -> int:
    return arr[0]
```

Running `mypy` on `demo1.py` gives no errors, but running it on `demo2.py` with either `numpy.ndarray` gives the error:

```
demo2.py:1: error: Name "numpy" is not defined
```

or `np.ndarray` gives the error:

```
demo2.py:1: error: Name "np" is not defined
```

So if I were designing a module `demo2.py` first, intending it to accept numpy arrays before I designed `demo1.py`, `mypy` would give an error.

Is there a better/"proper" way to handle the above situation?

Comment: Have you tried it? What happened?

Comment: Fair point. Let me do a quick demo script to test. I'm also unsure if I should use `"numpy.ndarray"` or `"np.ndarray"`, just fyi.

Comment: Please see my edit.

Comment: Thanks. Good question. Unfortunately my type hinting knowledge is rudimentary at best.

Comment: No problem at all. Same here. I think like most people, I'm learning as I go (it's still fairly new to me). I think this is a good question because I could foresee having to import the same packages in every module I want to use type hinting, even if I don't need to use the package directly. That's a lot of extra import calls.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python type hinting without cyclic imports](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39740632/python-type-hinting-without-cyclic-imports)

Comment: @AlexWaygood It's certainly helpful, yes. Thanks for that! I saw this earlier, but I mentally missed it because I was thinking about 3rd-party packages instead of those I created myself. Also, I didn't even taking cyclic imports into account in my question!

Comment: It works just the same for third-party packages as it does for ones you've created yourself :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, you can't.

You will need to have the names in scope (after all, you could have done a Ministry of Silly Imports and done `import math as np`), but you can use [`typing.TYPE_CHECKING`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.TYPE_CHECKING) if you don't want to really import the module:

```
from typing import TYPE_CHECKING

if TYPE_CHECKING:  # never true unless you're a type checker
    import numpy as np

def my_func(arr: "np.ndarray") -> int:
    pass  # does some operations with arr
```

Beyond that, type checkers don't (or shouldn't) care what you call the things; they'll resolve the symbols to their best capability, and e.g. this should work: <sub>(but please don't...)</sub>

```
from typing import TYPE_CHECKING

if TYPE_CHECKING:  # never true unless you're a type checker
    import numpy as noooooooooop
    bazoop = noooooooooop.ndarray
    glerp = int

def my_func(arr: "bazoop") -> "glerp":
    pass  # does some operations with arr
```

Comment: Thanks! Quick follow up: my knowledge of the `import` statement is rusty. In a multi-file project, if I've already imported `numpy` in one file, does the interpreter re-import `numpy` if I say `import numpy` in other files? Does doing the `if TYPE_CHECKING` check help prevent against "re-imports"?

Comment: The interpreter only ever imports modules once (and stashes them into `sys.modules` but let's not talk about that). That is, there are no "re-imports" in Python over the lifetime of an interpreter unless you use `reload()` or muck about with `sys.modules`/`sys.path`/`sys.meta_path`/....

Comment: And to follow up a bit: an import within `if TYPE_CHECKING:` means the import never occurs at runtime, since `TYPE_CHECKING` isn't ever true at runtime. This means it's safe to even do circular imports within those blocks (since type checkers can afford to be smarter than Python when resolving imports, as they don't really execute code that could have side effects).

Comment: Ah circular imports...I didn't think of that. All of this is good to know. Thank you!