# Python 3.10 new literal alternative in dataclass

Tags: python, typing

I have such piece of code

```py
import strawberry


@strawberry.input
class CreateUserInput:
    username: str
    password: str
    email: str
    gender: 'M' | 'F'
```

but it throws an error `undefined name 'M'` (same for 'F').

I know I can import `Literal` type but can I somehow do this with the new way?

Comment: `gender: 'M' | 'F'` here means that gender is either type `M` or type `F`, but you want it to mean that it is a single character, restricted in value to either `'M'` or `'F'`, correct?

Comment: I think you misinterpreted what `|` is supposed to be doing. It's merely a syntactic sugar for `typing.Union[type1, type2]`. It doesn't have anything to do with `typing.Literal` (which is available since Python 3.8)

Comment: @Grismar yes. this is exactly what I mean. I thought this is similar to typescript's literals.

Comment: Python 3.10 added new syntax for union types. It did not change the syntax for literal types. There is no "new way" to write literal types.

Comment: You don't need runtime check  that the value of `gender` is a valid value, right? how are you currently building `CreateUserInput` objects?

Answer (score 3):

In type hints, an expression like `A | B` means the same as `Union[A, B]`, that is the type can be either `A` or `B`.

If you want to restrict a variable to specific literal values in a type hint, you need to use `Literal`, so you do need:

```
    gender: Literal['M', 'F']
```

You cannot replace it with `|`, as that has a completely different meaning.

Also note that type hints don't actually do anything at runtime. If you need more than just a type hint, you may want to look at enums, or defining a simple class that restricts values according to your needs.

Answer (score 0):

The other answer and comments explained how you should do it correctly, but haven't explained why the way you have tried to do it cannot work (which is very confusing when you're coming from e.g. TS).

In Python type hints, giving a string as a type, like this:

```
var: "Something" = "value"
```

... does not mean that the value should be the string `"Something"`, but should be of type `Something`. So, the text inside quotes is interpreted as a type name. Why? Because it allows to set the type to something that isn't yet available at that point in code at runtime, and putting a reference to that type in a string won't raise an error, but it will allow the type checker in your IDE to know what type to expect. See [PEP484](https://peps.python.org/pep-0484/#forward-references) (forward references). It's a great way to avoid circular dependencies, but now it can also be done with `from __future__ import annotations` (see [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39757388/4088140)).

So, when you're doing something like `gender: 'M' | 'F'` it means that the gender should be of type `M` or `F`, and the type checker looks for classes named like that, and raises `undefined name 'M'` error when that fails.

That's why literal types must be specified like `gender: Literal['M', 'F']` or `gender: Literal['M'] | Literal['F']`, it cannot be done like `gender: 'M' | 'F'` because that syntax is already used for these forward references.