# How to avoid cycling import when type hinting method return type in Python?

Tags: python, python-import

So this is old issue with many topics open on this. I found this one [Python type hinting without cyclic imports](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39740632/python-type-hinting-without-cyclic-imports) where the top answers suggests to use for example:

```
from typing import TYPE_CHECKING
if TYPE_CHECKING:
    from main import Main
```

this works for most typing cases but not for type hinting return types. For example if I have this:

```
from typing import TYPE_CHECKING
if TYPE_CHECKING:
    from main import Main
def func()->Main:
    return Main()
```

I get an error: `NameError: name 'Main' is not defined`

Any way to get something like this working for return types?

Answer (score 0):

Ok I think I found a workaround and it doesnt seem to have any negative side effects as far as I can see.

Instead of defining the return type just with the name of the class `Main` for example the class name has to go within single quotes. So the working equivalent of the example in the original question would be:

```
from typing import TYPE_CHECKING

if TYPE_CHECKING:
    from main import Main
def func()->'Main':
    return Main()
```

this works with no errors.