# defining a type hint in python for user defined class

Tags: python, type-hinting

If one has a method that takes in an arbitrary user defined class, and that class is defined in another part of the package, do I need to import that class in order to type hint it (so it is defined)?

```
from whatever import myClass

def doSomethingWithMyClass(an_instance_of_myClass: myClass)->None:
    #etc..
```

Even though I otherwise would not need to `import myClass` if I was not type hinting?

Comment: What happened when you tried both options (importing and not importing)?

Comment: @mkrieger1 my IDE certainly complains about the lack of definition. However I have seen a lot of of examples of "quoting" the class name instead. Im just trying to compromise between fully taking advantage of type hinting and not cluttering up the name space...

Comment: Also see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39740632/python-type-hinting-without-cyclic-imports

Answer (score 1):

A few niggles:

- `myClass` ought to be called `MyClass`.
- You would `from somewhere import MyClass`, since you can't import a class directly, as if it were a module.
- `theClass: myCLass` is probably `the_object: MyClass`, because if you want to pass the *class* as a parameter, its type would be `type`, not `MyClass`, and it would be `the_class: type`.

Having said that, yes you would need to import the class to type hint. However, if the only reason you need the import is the type hint, apparently you're not doing anything inside the function that actually *requires* the type to be declared/hinted. If you did, you would have other warnings or runtime errors to contend with and *that* would be the reason to restrict type, and then that would be the reason to import it.

If it is just about the type hint, either you want inherited classes to have the same restriction (and to make the restriction clear, you need to import it to make it explicit what exactly you're restricting to), or your code doesn't really care about the restriction and it's just decoration - in which case you can just leave the type hint off.

Another way to look at it: if you were to hint the type, but not import it, how is Python or your IDE supposed to know which type you're referring to? All you're saying at that point is "this variable has to be of some type named 'MyClass', but what that type is exactly doesn't matter, it is just the name I care about".