# How to avoid recursive imports?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a `Bot` class in `bot.py`:

```
import events


class Bot:
    def __init__(self, token, v):
        self.token = token
        self.v = v
        self.events = events.Events(self)
```

And also the `events.py` file:

```
import bot


class NewMessageEvent:
    def __init__(self, bot: bot.Bot):
        self.bot = bot
        self.someVar = "someVar"
        self.someVar2 = "someVar2"
        self.sender_id = "some_id"
        self.event_id = "some_id2"
        self.handlers = []
    
    def subscribe(self, handler):
        self.handlers.append(handler)

    def execute(self):
        for func in self.handlers:
            func(self)
    

class Events:
    def __init__(self, bot: bot.Bot):
        self.MESSAGE_NEW = NewMessageEvent(bot)
        #self.SMTH_ANOTHER = SomeAnotherEvent(bot)
```

You need all this to use it later on like this:

```
import bot
import events

mybot = bot.Bot("token", "api version")

def send_pic(event: events.NewMessageEvent):
    requests.get("link", headers = {"token": event.bot.token, "reply_to": event.sender_id})

mybot.events.MESSAGE_NEW.subscribe(send_pic)
```

As you can see, I got a recursive import. The `Bot` class uses the `Events` class, and in the `Events` class I need to specify a type hint for the `bot` argument (`bot.Bot`)

Is there any way to avoid recursive importing?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python type hinting without cyclic imports](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39740632/python-type-hinting-without-cyclic-imports)

Comment: Does this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67673741/4834) help at all?