# How do I avoid circular imports when using sqlalchemy relationship() with type annotations?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, python-typing

I'm declaring my models like so:

```py
from __future__ import annotations

class Parent(Base):
    ...
    children: Mapped[list[Child]] = relationship("Child", back_populates="parent")

class Child(Base):
    ...
    parent_id: Mapped[Optional[str]] = mapped_column(String, ForeignKey("parrent.id", name="parent_id_fk", ondelete="CASCADE"),  nullable=True, default=None)
    parent: Mapped[Parent] = relationship("Parent", back_populates="children")
```

This works fine, the problem starts when I want to separate these models to different files. How can I achieve this while still maintaining type annotations and the same capabilities, and avoiding circular imports?

Comment: There is a sense in which the type checker can "import" modules as necessary to do typechecking; you don't need to actually import `parent.py`, for example, just to annotate something with `parent.Parent`, *especially* if you are using the `annotations` future.

Comment: Consider, too, whether there is any *need* to separate such "conjoined" classes into separate modules.

Comment: @chepner I have a pretty large app with multiple models. The dependencies between them are such that not separating them will force me to have all models in the same file, this is untenable. 

With regards to the annotations - there is also the same problem with the relationship itself, even without the type annotations on it, i.e. 
```children = relationship("Child", backpopulates="parent", uselist=True)```

Would also fail.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python type hinting without cyclic imports](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39740632/python-type-hinting-without-cyclic-imports)

Comment: @InSync Unfortunately no, the problem is a combination of typing issues and sqlalchemy issues.

Specifically, you can set up the relationship members later (after class definition) in some other file, but then everywhere in the code, I'll have type-checkers like mypy shouting at me. 

My current solution forces me to import the child before importing the parent, and then adding some # noqa on the unused import. 

Perhaps I could hack some kind of solution by playing around with models/__init__.py assuming all my model files are in that directory.