# Checking the child / parent relationship of a class while preventing circular import / circular dependency

Tags: python, python-3.x, circular-dependency

I have these modules:

```python
# module 1

from abc import ABC
from module3 import AnotherClass


class Parent(ABC):

    @classmethod
    def func1(cls):

        other_param = "foo"
        AnotherClass.some_func(cls, other_param)
```

```python
# module 2

from module1 import Parent
from module3 import AnotherClass


class Child1(Parent):

    pass


class Child2(Parent):

    pass
```

```python
# module 3

from module1 import Parent # only for checking if the object is a subclass of Parent


class AnotherClass(object):

    @classmethod
    def some_func(cls, child_cls, other_param):

        assert issubclass(child_cls, Parent)
        # do other stuff
```

now if I do this:

```python
c1 = Child1()

c1.func1()
```

I rightfully get an ImportError complaining from a circular import as follows:

> ImportError: cannot import name 'Parent' from partially initialized
>   module 'module1' (most likely due to a circular import)

Actually `AnotherClass` does not depend on `Parent` or any of the Child classes, I'm importing the `Parent` only for checking if the passed class is a subclass of `Parent`, in this row:

```
assert issubclass(child_cls, Parent)
```

Now, I can defer importing of the `Parent` like this:

```python
# module 3


class AnotherClass(object):

    @classmethod
    def some_func(cls, child_cls, other_param):

        from module1 import Parent # only for type checking
        assert issubclass(child_cls, Parent)
        # do other stuff
```

And it works like a charm. But for some reason (unknown to me) I feel uncomfortable doing it this way.

Now my question is, can I sleep with peace deferring the import like that, or would it bite me in some way later on down the road?

If yes, how would you suggest I do the this parent / child relationship check at `AnotherClass.some_func()`?

**P.S.**
Before anyone brings it up, I know this topic of circular dependencies has been asked and answered many many times (such as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2461907/python-circular-imports-needed-for-type-checking)), but I'm asking if this specific solution is feasible and problem-free in the long run.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's nothing inherently wrong with your current solution. In this case you could also solve it like this though, which is imo a bit cleaner:

```
import module1


class AnotherClass(object):

    @classmethod
    def some_func(cls, child_cls, other_param):
        assert issubclass(child_cls, module1.Parent)
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you are not really doing "type checking" there, `assert`s are a completely different thing, since they are actually processed at run time.

I think you'd be best off using actual type-hints, and by using them there's a really simple and idiomatic way to avoid issues with circular imports:

```
from typing import TYPE_CHECKING

if TYPE_CHECKING:
    from module1 import Parent


class AnotherClass:  # No need to inherit from `object` in Python 3.

    @classmethod
    def some_func(cls, child_cls: "Parent", other_param):
        ...
```

Comment: You're right, it is not a type check. I've updated the question accordingly. 

Another problem was, I did not explicitly state that I want to check a parent / child (subclass) relationship between the two classes, not the type of it (it is kind of subtle)

Therefore, I cannot use this solution because what I really wanna do is not type checking, as you stated. I wanna check if `child_cls` is a subclass of the `Parent`